# Where in Europe can I find an aircraft turned into a hotel?

Tags: europe, hotels, where-on-earth, aircraft

I just found out that in Sweden there is [an old Boeing 747 turned into a hotel](http://www.jumbostay.com/). Where else in Europe can I find something like this? The closer to Germany, the better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an aircraft hostel in Canada or USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8368/is-there-an-aircraft-hostel-in-canada-or-usa)

Comment: @Karlson related - yes, but no dublicate, since I'm asking for Europe and not for America

Comment: Yep.  You're right.  My bad.  Here is another one related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/is-there-a-website-dedicated-to-odd-hotels

Comment: Isn't his a list question ... ?

Comment: Marcel - doesn't it depend on the number of responses? A question that'll only ever have a few should be fine, while one that could have 10s to 100s isn't

Comment: it's a list question but with "very specific criteria" so it meets the rules entirely in my opinion

Comment: And asked by a high rep user. That makes a difference too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Netherlands there is this [Airplane suite](http://www.hotelsuites.nl/suites.php?hotel=1894&view=detail)

> The entire airplane has been converted into a single luxury suite for two guests. This means you have the complete craft at your disposal – including its top-flight facilities, which include a Jacuzzi, separate shower, infrared sauna, mini bar, 3 flat screen televisions, blu-ray DVD player with a comprehensive collection of DVDs, a pantry with oven/microwave combination, coffee and tea maker, free wireless internet, air conditioning, etc.
>
> PRICE:
>   An overnight stay for 2 persons including a luxury breakfast costs € 350. The airplane is available to you from 15:00 on the day of your arrival to 11:00 on the day of your departure.

There's also a [sneak peak video featured by the BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/8164639.stm)

Comment: Why do you need 3 televisions for 2 people?

Answer (score 5):

Just recently (yesterday), a [hotel in Vlaardingen](http://devreemdevogel.nl/buitenhotel/de-ijzeren-vogel) (close to Rotterdam) opened, and they also have a plane to stay in.

The website is only in Dutch (so far), but to summarize:

> The room is suitable for 2 to 4 people, and the cockpit is equipped with a flight simulator. Pricing starts from €290 for a weekend.